# Win32 Console Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have the `VS2017` community and I am lost: the Win32 Console Application is missing.

I don't even have template when I go to New Project and also I cannot create C++ Empty Project in VS2019.

I download almost everything from installer.

How I can solve it?
!

Comment: In the "New Project" dialog window, did you select "Installed"->"Visual C++" in the left menu?

Comment: Run the installer again, be sure to select the C++ workload.

Comment: i have "Visual C++ 2019" version and I installed almost all workloads. I cant understand why  win32 is still missing. I dont wont reinstall visual because i have files that i dont wont lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Win32 templates have been renamed to Windows Desktop.

In VS2017, If you want to create the Win32 Console Application,I suggest you could choose File->New->Project. And then choose `Windows Desktop Wizard`.As shown below:

[image]

If you want to create Win32 Console Application, you could select `Console Application(.exe)` in Application type. If you want to create the Empty Project, you could check `Empty Project`

[image]

In vs2019, if you want to create a Win32 console application, the steps are similar to in vs2017:
1,From the main menu, choose File > New > Project to open the Create a New Project dialog box.

2,At the top of the dialog, set Language to C++, set Platform to Windows, and set Project type to Desktop.

3,From the filtered list of project types, choose Windows Desktop Wizard

[image]

4,Under Application type, select Desktop application (.exe). Under Additional options, select Empty project.

[image]